# WSO2 IS 5.4.1 - Unable to configure the added Identity Providers (IdP) with service provider

Tags: wso2, adfs3.0, wso2-identity-server

**Application Brief**:
 WSO2 IS(version - 5.4.1) is working as Federer Identity Server for our application, Where ADFS(version - 3.0) will be IdP. WSO2 IS to ADFS communication will be through SAML2 Web SSO Configuration and Application to WSO2 IS communication will be using OpenId connect. 
 1) Created a sample application and added it on WSO2 IS as service provider - (able to login and redirected back to configured login page for the Resident IdP)
 2) Added Identity Provider (ADFS) using management console.

**Problem statement**:
 While configuring the "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" for service provider, "Federated Authentication" option is not getting enabled as well as dropdown list for the same doesn't reflect the available (newly added) IdP's. Hence coludn't able to configure the IdP's added through management console. But I am able to do the configuration when I add IdP through the file configuration (as Shared).

**Queries**:
 1) Why  "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration"-->  "Federated Authentication" option is not getting enabled after adding the extenal IdP in the "Identity Providers". 
 2) Using the [file based IdP configuration](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files) (only IdP configuration), I am able to map it to the service provider as  "Federated Authentication"  in  "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" (management console has more properties than the proved sample IdP config xml) but still it is not working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1st question, have you enabled the SAML SSO for the ADFS IDP? Refer attached image.

[image]

The given information is not sufficient to answer the second question. However you can try again once you manage to add ADFS as a federated IDP. You can refer [this post](https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/) for more information on configuring ADFS with IS.